# Which channel type should be used when the message is never evaluated?

Tags: go

With the following select statement I want to ensure that some none-blocking function is only executed one by one:

```golang
select {
case <-available:
default:
    fmt.Println("busy")
    return
}
go func() {
    defer func() { available <- true }()
    doSomethingOneByOne()
}()
```

Currently I'm using `bool` as a channel type and it works as expected.

What I don't like is that using `bool` suggests that it matters if the value is `true` or `false`. But actually it doesn't matter in this case. In my opinion this makes understanding the code a bit harder because it is misleading.

Is there a convention for which type to use when the value doesn't matter?

Comment: Use an empty struct.

Comment: As long as you do not evaluate the value taken from the channel, I do not see a problem. And you can use Godoc/comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`chan struct{}` is a valid choice — `struct{}` is a valid type, but a value of this type [contains no data and has zero size](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct), and all `struct{}` values are indistinguishable, making it a [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) for Go. To construct a value of type `struct{}` to send on the channel, you can use the literal `struct{}{}`.

Comment: I frequently end up defining `type Sentinel struct{}` and `var Nothing = Sentinel{}` just to keep code readable and because having `struct{}{}` everywhere just looks messy to me.